# How to do appsetting variable substitution with CodeDeploy

Tags: aws-code-deploy

I currently have a .net web api that's in my CodePipeline.

It builds and deploys fine but now I need to make it be aware of what environment it's in and update the appsettings accordingly.

For example, it should update the the dev connection string to be CI or Production

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables to configure the right value for the appropriate environment.

Here are links with additional info. I hope they help you.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/environment-variables-with-net-core-and-elastic-beanstalk/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configuration-keys-and-values

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't provide how code pipeline is to update appsettings.